# Incorrect theorem in preparation for polar decomposition in notes?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, lu-decomposition

Theorem 2.3 [here](http://buzzard.ups.edu/courses/2014spring/420projects/math420-UPS-spring-2014-buffington-polar-decomposition.pdf) says that if $A$ is normal it has a positive semi-definite square root.

Isn't this wrong? In particular the fourth sentence of the proof claims the eigenvalues of normal matrices are positive, which seems way off...

Comment: You're correct. That theorem is nonsense. Any diagonal real matrix with some negative entry is a counterexample.

Comment: Apparently "normal" is a typo for "positive semi-definite".